# Which of these is correct: "The team consists of John and I/me/myself."?

Tags: pronouns

Which of these is correct: "The team consists of John and I/me/myself."? I'm confused here, since none of the options feel right...

Comment: Which would you use if you were the only person on the team?

Comment: That's the weird part. Here in Pakistan, the majority of the population uses **myself**, and even while I was living in Canada, **myself** was more common, but it didn't feel right. Not being a native English speaker myself, I wanted to know the rules, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard test to figure this out is to ask which pronoun would be correct if you took everything else out. In other words, we ask which of the following is correct:

> - The team consists of I.
> - The team consists of me.
> - The team consists of myself.

"I" is wrong because the pronoun is not a subject. *Technically*, "myself" is also wrong because the pronoun is not being used in a reflexive way ("I" is not also the subject). So the answer is "me": **The team consists of John and me.** (To my ear, "... of me and John" sounds better; both are correct.)

**But,** you will very often find native speakers saying "myself" here! If you're interested in more details on this, read on. If not, you can stop reading here: "me" is the grammatically correct answer even though you may hear/see "myself" sometimes.

---

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun):

> Some speakers use reflexive pronouns without local linguistic antecedents to refer to discourse participants or people already referenced in a discourse: for example, "Please, forward the information to myself, Anything else for yourself today?". Within the linguistics literature, reflexives with discourse antecedents are often referred to as logophors. Standard English allows use of logophors in some contexts: for example, "John was angry. Embarrassing pictures of himself were on display." However, within Standard English, this logophoric use of reflexives is generally limited to positions where the reflexive does not have a coargument.
>
> ...
>
> It is also common in informal speech to use myself in a conjunctive phrase when the pronoun 'me' would be more economical and grammatical as with "She stood by Jane and myself." Leaving Jane out of it, "She stood by myself" would probably sound better as "She stood by me." Hence, "She stood by Jane and me" can be seen as more grammatically correct.

This "less correct" usage is, I think, becoming more and more common. If you said "myself" instead of "me" in this particular case, I don't think anyone but a grammarian would notice.

Comment: Many careful English speakers are annoyed to hear or see 'myself' used in place of 'me' - e.g. The report was written by John and myself.

Comment: Edit: "I don't think anyone but a grammarian or @MichaelHarvey would notice." ;-)

Comment: Aren't we supposed to be answering or commenting as "grammarians" (whatever you intend that to mean)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think that's closer to ELU's mission statement. As a language learner myself (of German and in the past, French) I like to know what's technically right as well as any common deviations from strict rules. If I ever become a German professor (extremely unlikely!) my perspective will no doubt change!

Comment: Many English speakers feel that using 'myself' instead of 'me' is done by the ignorant to appear more dignified or important. [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/me_myself.htm) says: "You cannot use "myself" for any other reason [than as a pronoun following "I"]. You cannot use it because it sounds better than "me.", [or] when someone other than "you" is doing something to "you." For example: He raised the issue with myself. Please send any complaints to your line manager or myself. The 100% Rule: If you're going to use "myself," the subject of the verb must be "I."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey To be clear I'm not disputing the rule - I agree with everything you just said and I think my answer is consistent with that by stating what is actually correct. I then simply go on to make the point that a lot of people break this particular rule in this situation. That is a fact whether we like it or not, and a fact that may be useful to a learner.

Comment: I agree that we should acquaint ESL learners with common errors and relaxations of 'rules', but we need to be clear where the boundary lies.

Comment: I feel that this answer, although correct in every way, is rather heavily 'linguistic' for ELL.

Comment: I made a small edit instructing those not inclined to an "overly linguistic" discussion to stop reading. Hopefully this addresses the concerns. I really don't think deliberately omitting potentially useful information is a good thing. Incidentally, I tried to move the discussion to chat but got an error message ("Moving the discussion to chat failed").

Answer (score 1):

**"The team consists of John and I/me/myself."**

Only "The team consists of John and me" is correct.

You will hear "I" from native speakers who are hypercorrecting.

You will hear "myself" from speakers who don't know which is correct and are trying to avoid being wrong by compromising.

> hypercorrection /hʌɪpəkəˈrɛkʃ(ə)n/ noun
>
> 1. the use of an erroneous word form or pronunciation based on a false analogy with a correct or prestigious form, such as the use of I
>    instead of me as a grammatical object (as in he invited my husband and
>    I to lunch). Powered by Oxford Dictionaries